# "Invalid UTF8 line" when importing mysqldump

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to import a mysqldump script into google cloud SQL and the process is failing with the error "Invalid UTF8 line" at a given line in my script

The script can be imported on my local MySQL instance with no problem
I exported my structure & date using following command line :
mysqldump -umyUser -p --routines --all-databases -r /tmp/mysqldump.sql

And my server is set to UTF8 (at the beginning of the sql file, I have :

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database:
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.73-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Any idea about what is going bad about the file encoding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive an error such as ‘invalid UTF8 line’ error, this generally means that the values that you are inserting are not in UTF8 format.

I recommend retrying the export and using the following flags: ‘--hex-blob’ and ‘'--default-character-set=utf8'. This is mentioned as a suggestion in the Cloud SQL FAQ under [‘Notable Differences’](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq?hl=en#supportmysqlfeatures) between MySQL and Cloud SQL.

For a full list of mysqldump options, please see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

I hope that this information is helpful.